# MySQL: How to get values from Multiple Columns in one column

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with data. "keywords" and "Data".

```
key_id (P)
key_word
key_prod (I)
kay_country
key_is_wr
```

and

```
id (P)
dat_id (I)
dat_date
dat_is_weekly
```

For each keyword there are a few different rows linked in the data table - with different or the **same dates** in `dat_date`. I want to get all variations of dates that exist in this table only once so i can display them all in an array on my PHP code.

This is the query im currently using - it gets me a list of the same dates from the specific "key_app" value I need. But I only want to get an array of dates that exist for this specific key_id.

```
SELECT * FROM `keywords` 
    JOIN `data` 
    ON `keywords`.`key_id` = `data`.`dat_id`
    WHERE `keywords`.`key_app`= 10
```

I Just haven't figure out yet how to: 
 1. Get only the dat_date section (I guess i need `data`.`dat_date` instead of the "*" in my query. 
 2. How to get only the different dates that exist for each `key_prod`.

I tried using all sorts of ORDER BY and MAX(id) and nothing seem to work well in terms of sytaxes

```
SELECT * FROM `keywords` 
    JOIN ( 
            SELECT MAX(id) AS id 
            FROM `data` 
            GROUP BY `data`.`dat_date` 
        ) `keywords`
    ON `keywords`.`key_prod`=10
```

I have been digging it for a while but no right result

Example: 
If I have under `dat_date` the vars

```
2016-06-21
2016-06-21
2016-06-21
2016-06-22
2016-06-22
2016-06-23
2016-06-23
```

for a specific `key_app` - I will get:

```
2016-06-21
2016-06-22
2016-06-23
```

as a query result

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
select distinct data.dat_date
FROM `keywords`, `data` 
ON `keywords`.`key_prod` = `data`.`dat_id`
WHERE `keywords`.`key_app`= 10
```

Your first query was how to display only the date. This can be done using `select data.dat_date` instead of `select *`.
`Distinct` will list only distinct dates not the same dates which was your query 2.